# Loading Seaside onto Pharo 2.0

Tags: pharo, seaside

Pharo 2.0 was released recently.  I downloaded it, and tried running this:

```
Gofer new
    squeaksource: 'MetacelloRepository';
    package: 'ConfigurationOfSeaside30';
    load.
(Smalltalk at: #ConfigurationOfSeaside30) load.
```

It completed but it didn't create a 'Seaside Control Panel' menu option in the Tools submenu of the World menu.

What are the next steps to take?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The control panel was built using OB, which is not available anymore for Pharo 2.0

Therefore, you need to start an adaptor programmatically. In Pharo 2.0, the default adaptor has become the Zinc adaptor. You can start it by executing the following expression:

```
ZnZincServerAdaptor startOn: 8080
```

This starts the adaptor on port 8080.